# Remorseless Riddle Rampages Relentlessly

Tags: knowledge, wordplay, cipher, story, poetry

"Fine day" says I
"Need a sardine?"
"Why - no thank you"
- replied Cecil the 3-Eyed Spleen

"How then will you get in
Through that nasty great door?" I ask.
He said "Slowly - slowly - lather myself with Cod Oil
Which, incidentally, lives in this here flask".

"Come now" says I
Not one for games.
"That'll never work
Look at those flames!"

"Ah - Yes" says he
As he takes a slurp
"Story of my life"
And he proceeds to botty-burp.

/

"So...
Here we are stuck.
forever and ever..."

Never to enter. the hallowed halls of -
"Trevor!" cries Cecil-Spleen " - thank Goodness you're here"
"Ah" replies the walrus "there's something you're missing".

"It's not a thing you need with which to enter this door
rather a word or two like 'edible seeds'
or 3 like 'Samuel Eff' WASP! Ahh! get it off me
and write this down you'll see"

---

HINT

> 1. Please do NOT edit the puzzle - however bad the punctuation might be
>  2. Key to the answer is in the second to last line and the title
>  3. In the 2nd last line, instead of WASP! it should read BEE!

Comment: Well, the 3rd hint is clear, now how to figure out the pattern...

Comment: Well, 2nd AND third together, that is.

Comment: I have no idea what the answer is supposed to be, but it's intriguing.

Comment: The hints refer to Samuel Morse (Samuel F B Morse, also see puzzle title) so Morse code is involved, I just don't see *how*

Comment: Nice puzzle for the classical cryptographer!

Comment: Hey, Ben, I see you're actively editing this. Did I get the answer right or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The password is

> OPEN SESAME

Before the slash,

> take the "." and "-" characters from each stanza to make a single Morse character.

After the slash,

> do it line by line instead.

The essential clue, as Irishpanda observes, is in the title and the penultimate line.

Comment: Yes! It's right. Well done. Will award the bounty soon. Was hoping for more interest in this - I thought it was a pretty good (..and not too hard) puzzle... Looks like it didn't hit off for some reason. :-(

Comment: It seems to be pretty random what catches people's interest.

Comment: Anyway, if the answer is right then you should accept it by clicking the little green checkmark thing on the left. (If other puzzles you've posed have been correctly solved, you should do it there, too.) This is a separate operation from awarding bounties, though if you set up a bounty, accept an answer, and then do nothing else, the bounty will eventually go to the answer you accepted.

Comment: ok. will do. I just thought that it might attract more attention if the answer wasn't accepted yet...

Comment: Ah, tactics. OK.